# How do I avoid spaces/tabs in columns names when I use proc transpose?

Tags: sas, transpose

How do I avoid spaces/tabs in columns names when I use proc transpose? The best way to illustrate my problem is by giving an example:

```
Data tst; input ColA $ ColB; datalines;
    Cat1 1
    Cat2 2
    Cat3 3
; run;
proc transpose data = tst out= tst_out (drop = _name_); id ColA;
run;
```

When running this code my column names look something like this:
[image]

Basically I want the column names to be `"Cat1", "Cat1", "Cat1"` and not `" Cat1", "    Cat1", "    Cat1"`.

(If that is not possible then I have an alternative question: How do I remove the spaces AFTER proc transpose? In my real data set I have a lot of columns so I prefer a method where I don't have to type for every column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the setting of VALIDVARNAME option to V7 instead of ANY. It won't remove the leading spaces/tabs but it will change them to underscores so the result are valid names.

Example:

```
data tst;
  input ColA $& ColB; 
datalines;
Cat 1  1
Cat 2  2
Cat 3  3
; 
options validvarname=v7;
proc transpose data=tst out=tst2; id cola ; var colb; run;
proc print;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs    _NAME_    Cat_1    Cat_2    Cat_3

 1      ColB       1        2        3
```

PS When using in-line data in your SAS program make sure to start the lines of data in the first column.  That will prevent the accidental inclusion of spaces (or tabs when using SAS/Studio interface) in the lines of data.  Placing the DATALINES (also known as CARDS) statement starting in the first column will also prevent the editor from automatically indenting when you start adding lines of data.